# Nested form of XML in ANT build.xml

Tags: xml, ant, syntax, nested-forms

I am a newbie to both ANT and XML. The XML syntax seems really confusing. 
The following three structures of "echo" are correct in my ANT.

```
  <echo message="Hello "/>
  <echo message="Hello "></echo>
  <echo> Hello </echo>
```

but when I use "fileset",

```
<fileset dir="." includes = "**/*.java" id="myid" />
<fileset dir="." includes = "**/*.java" id="myid2" ></fileset>
```

are still correct, but

```
  <fileset> dir="." includes = "**/*.java" id="myid2" </fileset>
```

are considered wrong by ANT:

```
The <fileset> type doesn't support nested text data ("dir="." ...="myid2"").
```

Is there some general rule to distinguish the syntax difference between the headings such as **"fileset"** and **"echo"**, I mean, how can **"echo"** permits nested text data but **"fileset"** does not?
Thanks.

Comment: Ant developers do not provide users with any schemas/DTDs, because of Ant's nature - you can easy define new tasks, types with their own features. So there is no any syntax check while defining build.xml. Ant tasks in XML are parsed by task Java code, so you can know what is supported only by reading docs/viewing source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authors of [echo task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) developed it in such a dual-use way. It can operate with "message" attribute or with child text. But other tasks ([fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) is actually a type) do not support such features. Just read official documentation to know all use-cases.